# AudioKit: Pull from develop branch from Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods, audiokit

Is there a way to for AudioKit Pod to pull from develop branch? I'm running `pod 'AudioKit', :git => 'https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit.git', :branch => 'develop'` in the podfile. It starts to try and download the data but then the console says `Unable to find a specification for 'AudioKit’.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wanted this as well, but the AudioKit Cocoapod is distributed as pre-built framework files.

The good news though is that just yesterday develop was pushed to production and also the pod frameworks were built and distributed.  So it's pretty fresh right now.